# Cannot Properly Resize MKMapView in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, xib

I try to insert and resize a MKMapView via interface builder (xcode 4.5).
However, the simulator shows different size/position compare to what we see in IB.
Any hint where could go wrong ?

Thanks.

http://i463.photobucket.com/albums/qq355/popov_kai/Untitled3.png

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your textfield is pushed down by the navigation bar but the map is not. So in Interface Builder find the setting to simulate a navigation bar in your UI and then position your map according to that.